# JavaScript code works, but it also doesn't work

Tags: javascript, error-handling, compiler-errors

**Please: can somebody tell me...why oh why doesn't this code work for all test cases? Only some work. Below I will put the actual "incorrect" output under each "incorrect" test result. But aren't they indeed correct results after all? Am I simply formatting the outputted values incorrectly somehow since they do seem correct? Why is it saying my below test cases are incorrect...? Please help.** :(

> CODERBYTE.COM INCORRECT TEST CASE REPORTS (3/5 POINTS SCORED)--->
>
> > **1.** When the input was (78, 90, 100, 1, 2) your output was incorrect.
> >      MY ACTUAL RESULT: *var arr = [78, 90, 100, 1, 2] -outputs-> **90 2***
> >
> > **2.** When the input was (-4, -5, 10, 2) your output was incorrect.
> >      MY ACTUAL RESULT: *var arr = [-4, -5, 10, 2] -outputs-> **2 -4***
> >
> > **3.** When the input was (100, 200, 3, 400, 5, 1) your output was incorrect.
> >      MY ACTUAL RESULT: *var arr = [100, 200, 3, 400, 5, 1] -outputs-> **200 3***
> >
> > **4.** When the input was (4, 60, 7, 188) your output was incorrect.
> >      MY ACTUAL RESULT: *var arr = [4, 60, 7, 188] -outputs-> **60 7***

[begin code here]:

```
var arr = [...]; //unordered number list of varying sizes goes here

function SecondGreatLow(arr) {
    var input = arr.sort(function(a,b){return (a-b);});
    var hashObject = {};


    for (var i = input.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var currentItem = input[i];
    if (hashObject[currentItem] === true) {
        input.splice(i, 1);
    }
    hashObject[currentItem] = true;
    }
    //alert(input.length + " input.length before final answer returned");                           
    if (input.length > 3) {
      input.pop();
      input.shift();
        var min = Math.min.apply(null,input),
        max = Math.max.apply(null,input);
        return String(max) + " " + String(min);
    }
    else if (input.length === 3) {
      return String(input[1]) + " " + String(input[1]);
    } else {
        var min2 = Math.min.apply(null,input),
        max2 = Math.max.apply(null,input);
        return String(max2) + " " + String(min2);
    }
}

// keep this function call here 
// to see how to enter arguments in JavaScript scroll down
//SecondGreatLow(readline()); //FOR USE ON CODERBYTE.COM ONLY

console.log(SecondGreatLow(arr));
```

Comment: You appear to be asking us to debug your code. Do you know how to step through javascript code in a debugger?

Comment: I only know how to manually debug. Do you think it will help? I don't really understand why the code isn't producing correct values. The values seem correct, and produce "correct" results, but coderbyte deems them improper. I've tried wrapping the number output as a String to no avail.

Comment: http://i62.tinypic.com/veusco.png
-- Here is a screenshot showing that it does indeed seem to be providing output that's correct...yet on the above examples, you can see it clearly is labeled as "incorrect" output by coderbyte.

Comment: Could it be that Coderbyte is expecting the result to be `min2 max2` instead of `max2 min2`? Based on their example, they seem to be expecting the smallest first.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried setting it as you suggested:
They gave a correct test case example -> "Input = [4, 90] -> Output = 90 4". So, it can't be min2 max2, because for me that array produced -> 4 90, which is backwards and incorrect according to the other example. I'm so confused.